# Load last webpage UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

How can I make a button that will open a UIWebView the the last page that it was on before the user closed it?

for instance i have 2 xibs
1) my home screen
2) my webview

on my home screen i have 2 buttons

1) opens the webview to google.com
2) the second one opens the webview to the last page that it was on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the URL of the last page visited in the user's `NSUserDefaults` DB. When the button is clicked, read the value from `NSUserDefaults` and navigate to that URL in the UIWebView.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much took me 3 days to figure this out i was trying to save it to a plist file but it just wasnt working right. took me about 10 mins after you helped.